# How to import the images of products with a csv file via dataflow of Magento 1.6.2?

Tags: image, magento, import

Hi I have an issue with import of product images.

I use Magento 1.6.2 and I want to import products with the import dataflow of Magento. I have my images in media/import - i import my dataflow with all the rows.

Example: the image 12345.jpg is in media/import/1/2/12345.jpg In the csv it looks like: "/1/2/12345.jpg"

But when I want to import my csv it says: "The image doesn't exist."

Why? Help. Thx

Answer (score 1):

It needs to go in the media/import folder then the CSV just says /image.jpg (where image.jpg is the actual filename of the image you're using). There's [another answer I made with the details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341879/magento-import-products-with-images/10357766#10357766)... I'll see if I can find it and paste the correct details in here. That link also has working CSV samples from my successful import.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the slash should do the job:

```
"1/2/12345.jpg"
```

instead of

```
"/1/2/12345.jpg"
```