# CSV First Row Product status not updated in magento after update product programatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am run a script for update product programatically in magento. it is working fine when we added products but when we update products using this script and product csv file then first row product status not updated in magento admin panel.

this is the code of update function --

```
public function updateProduct($importData,$feed_category,$feed_margin)
    {

        $sku = trim($importData['sku']);
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

        if($this->getBatchParams('mark_up') == '') {
            $mark_up = '15';
        } else {
            $mark_up = $this->getBatchParams('mark_up');
        }

        if($this->getBatchParams('mark_up_type') == '') {
            $mark_up_type = 'percent';
        } else {
            $mark_up_type = $this->getBatchParams('mark_up_type');
        }

        $prprice = $importData['your_buy_ex_gst'];

        if($mark_up_type=='percent'){
            $prprice = ($prprice/(1-($feed_margin/100)));
        }
        else{
            $prprice = $prprice+$feed_margin;   
        }

        #Set attribute set id
        $productAttributeSets = $this->getProductAttributeSets ();
        if(!isset($importData ['attribute_set'])){
            if($this->getBatchParams('attribute_set') == '') {
                $importData ['attribute_set'] = 'data_feed';
            } else {
                $importData ['attribute_set'] = $this->getBatchParams('attribute_set');
            }
        }
        if(empty($importData ['attribute_set'] ) || ! isset ( $productAttributeSets [$importData ['attribute_set']] )) {
                $value = isset ( $importData ['attribute_set'] ) ? $importData ['attribute_set'] : '';
                $message = Mage::helper ( 'catalog' )->__ ( 'Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"', $value, 'attribute_set' );
                Mage::throwException ( $message );
            }
        $product->setAttributeSetId ( $productAttributeSets [$importData ['attribute_set']]);
        #END : Set attribute set id

        $product->setPrice($prprice);
        $product->setName($importData['name']);
        $product->setDescription($importData['description']);
        $product->setShortDescription($importData['description']);
        $product->setStatus(1);

        //$product->setData ($field, $setValue)

        #Adding the image to media gallery#
        $importData['image_large']=trim($importData['image_large']);
        if($importData['image_large'] != '')
        {
            $image_url  = $importData['image_large']; //get external image url from csv
            /*Checking if the image is real or corrupt*/
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = @getimagesize($image_url);
            if(isset($width) && $width!='' && isset($height) && $height!='' ){  
                $image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1); //find the image extension
                $filename   = md5($image_url . $importData['sku']).'.'.$image_type; //give a new name, you can modify as per your requirement
                $filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import'. DS . $filename; //path for temp storage folder: ./media/import/
                file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url))); //store the image from external url to the temp storage folder
                /*check again for corrupt image*/
                list($width_dk, $height_dk, $type_dk, $attr) = @getimagesize($filepath);
                if( isset($width_dk) && $width_dk!='' && isset($height_dk) && $height_dk!=''){  

                    /* Start deleting the old images from media gallery before insert */
                    if ($product->getId()){
                        $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
                        $items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());
                        foreach($items as $item)
                        $mediaApi->remove($product->getId(), $item['file']);
                    }
                    /* End deleting the old images from media gallery before insert */

                    $mediaAttribute = array (
                            'thumbnail',
                            'small_image',
                            'image'
                    );
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $mediaAttribute, true, false);

                } else {
                    /*One more try to get the imag right*/
                    @unlink($filepath);
                    $image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1); 
                    $filename   = md5($image_url . $importData['sku']).'.'.$image_type; 
                    $filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import'. DS . $filename; 
                    file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url)));  
                    list($width_dk, $height_dk, $type_dk, $attr) = @getimagesize($filepath);
                    if( isset($width_dk) && $width_dk!='' && isset($height_dk) && $height_dk!=''){
                        /* Start deleting the old images from media gallery before insert */
                        if ($product->getId()){
                            $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
                            $items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());
                            foreach($items as $item)
                            $mediaApi->remove($product->getId(), $item['file']);
                        }
                        /* End deleting the old images from media gallery before insert */

                        $mediaAttribute = array (
                                'thumbnail',
                                'small_image',
                                'image'
                        );
                        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $mediaAttribute, true, false);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        #Adding the image to media gallery#

        #Attribute mapping#
            foreach($importData as $field => $value){
            // if (in_array($field, $this->_inventorySimpleFields)) {works only for old version )
            if (in_array ( $field, $this->_inventoryFields )) {
                continue;
            }
            if (in_array ( $field, $this->_imageFields )) {
                continue;
            }

            $attribute = $this->getAttribute ( $field );
            if (! $attribute) {
                continue;
            }

            $isArray = false;
            $setValue = $value;

            if($attribute->getFrontendInput () == 'multiselect'){
                $value = split ( self::MULTI_DELIMITER, $value );
                $isArray = true;
                $setValue = array();
            }

            if($value && $attribute->getBackendType () == 'decimal'){
                $setValue = $this->getNumber ( $value );
            }

            if($value && $attribute->getBackendType () == 'datetime'){
                $setValue= date('Y-m-j', strtotime($value));
            }


            if($attribute->usesSource ()){
                $options = $attribute->getSource ()->getAllOptions ( false );

                if ($isArray) {
                    foreach ( $options as $item ) {
                        if (in_array ( $item ['label'], $value )) {
                            $setValue [] = $item ['value'];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $setValue = null;
                    foreach ( $options as $item ) {
                        if ($item ['label'] == $value) {
                            $setValue = $item ['value'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $product->setData ( $field, $setValue );
        }

        #Getting the store#
        if (empty ( $importData ['store'] )) {
            if($this->getBatchParams('store') == '') {
                $param_store = '2';
            } else {
                $param_store = $this->getBatchParams('store');
            }
            if (! is_null ( $param_store )) {
                    $store = Mage::app()->getStore( $param_store );
            } else {
                    $message = Mage::helper ( 'catalog' )->__ ( 'Skip import row, required field "%s" not defined', 'store' );
                    Mage::throwException ( $message );
            }
        } else {
                $store = $this->getStoreByCode ($importData['store']);
        }

        if($store === false){
            $message = Mage::helper ( 'catalog' )->__ ( 'Skip import row, store "%s" field not exists', $importData['store']);
            Mage::throwException ($message);
        }
        #END : Getting the store#

        //// Para importar categorias 
        $currentCatIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if(is_array($currentCatIds) && count($currentCatIds)>0){
            $cats = implode(',',$currentCatIds);        
            $cats = $cats.','.$feed_category;
            $product->setCategoryIds($cats);
        }
        else{
            $product->setCategoryIds($feed_category);
        }
        ////

        $product->setWeight($importData['weight']);

        $productId = $product->getId();
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
        $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();
        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);

        if($importData['weight'] == '' || $importData['weight'] == '0') {
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
        } else {
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
        }

        $stockItem->setData('qty', $importData['quantity']);
        $stockItem->save();

        try { 
            $product->save();
            //echo $importData['sku']. ' - updated' .'<br/>';
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex."<br><br><br>";
        }   


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here: [Magento import products with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341879/magento-import-products-with-images/10357766#10357766)

The first row has the keywords (or field names) in it.

Answer (score 0):

check in your csv or txt file Product status value. enable=1 disable=2. and Field Name "status" (csv header). (this is for Magento 1.4.)

Example.

"sku""status"

"Product1"  "1(For Enable Product)"

"Product2"  "2(For Disable Product)"

If you have any problem then show me your sample csv file.