# Bulk image upload via CSV in magento

Tags: magento

I can upload bulk product information via csv but cannot understand how to upload bulk product images via CSV file. Suppose I have 500 images. Then please explain me how can I upload that images via CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file with your products should have columns where you would put the products such as '_media_image' and 'thumbnail'.

The way I've learned that it should work is that you dump your images into /media/import then in the above mentioned image columns you would put "/image_name.jpg" for the product's image.

See: [Magento import products with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341879/magento-import-products-with-images) for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

In magento i have tryied to import all my product that are on my localhost to my live site but i was unable to do that. After a logn research and gooling i find my solution to import bulk product in magento. Go through this link.

http://www.ddcantt.in/2014/12/solved-how-to-import-export-product-in.html

Hope this will help you in exporting and importing product in bulk.